# Updating Jira ticket from jenkins 2 pipeline

Tags: groovy, jira, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

Hi I am implementing a jenkins 2 pipeline. I am trying to create a groovy function that will update a given story in Jira. I found the below code which I have been told should work.

```
step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater', 
issueSelector: [$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.selector.DefaultIssueSelector'], 
scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git']]]])
```

I am wondering how is the ticket specified using this? 
Would anyone be able to describe what is happening in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `Jira` pipeline-compatible plugin but from the [plugin's pipeline documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-issue-updater-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/info/bluefloyd/jenkins/IssueUpdatesBuilder/config.jelly) it appears that you can pass a number of parameters to `Jira's updater` such as :

> - Jira REST base url
> - Jira Username/Password
> - JQL for selecting issues to be updated
> - Jira comment to be added

I think a close look to this [documentation file](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-issue-updater-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/info/bluefloyd/jenkins/IssueUpdatesBuilder/config.jelly) will give you all the information you need, and once you know which parameters you should be able to call `Jira updater` with this kind of Groovy code :

```
step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater',
  restAPIUrl: yourJiraAPIUrl,
  jql: theJQLQueryThatWillFindYourIssuesToUpdate,
  comment: theComment,
  failIfJqlFails: true
)
```

The sample you provide does not seem to be correct because the two parameters `issueSelector` and `scm` are **not** valid parameters of the JiraIssueUpdater class.

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) for some sample, like :

> JiraIssueUpdateBuilder usage example

```
node {
    step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdateBuilder', 
        jqlSearch: "project = EX and labels = 'jenkins' and labels = '${version}'",
        workflowActionName: 'Resolve Issue',
        comment: 'comment'])
```